# Question about notation $S^c$

Tags: notation

I'm reading an article and came across a proposition. Simple question about notation, but cannot find it by googling. What does $S^c$ represent in the attached proposition below?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the complement of $S$.

That is: $S^c=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\ |\ x\not\in S\}$.

Comment: In this case the proposition is false: take $S=\mathbf N$.

Comment: @Bernard Indeed. Maybe there is something in the footnote, or maybe before the proposition there are some assumptions about $S$.

Comment: @ThePhenotype it mentions that the proposition is false in the article. Just wanted to understand the notation being used. Thanks.

Comment: @TyeCampbell Aha. Well, that probably explains the footnote then? :)